# Locate source of scroll event in legacy web application

Tags: browser, dom-events

I've inherited a web application that automatically scrolls the page to a certain element on load. I'm tasked with removing this behavior.

I've searched for obvious strings in the code like "scroll" but so far I'm unable to locate the source of this behavior - the code is big and old and kind of disorganized. Is there any way to intercept the scroll event in the debugger in order to locate the source?

Comment: There are 3 way's to scroll to elements: 1. set scrollTop with a number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop 2. call scrollIntoView on an element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView or 3. use a #hash-link in the URL.

Comment: Thanks, found the culprit. Stackoverflow is my rubber-duck debugging tool of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".some-element-class").offset().top
},150);
```

There are too many occurrences of "scroll" in jQuery and other libraries in the project and I missed this in the mess - then I started searching using the identifier of possible target elements and this narrowed down the number of matches.